# Java compare two sets filled with different instances of same object that satisfy equals()

Tags: java, equals, hashset

I've made a class called Coordinate as follows:

```
public class Coordinate {
    public int x;
    public int y;

    public Coordinate(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        Coordinate coordinate = (Coordinate)obj;
        return (coordinate.x == this.x && coordinate.y == this.y);
    }
}
```

I have two sets (A & B) that I fill with instances of the Coordinate class. I'd like to test if my two sets contain instances of Coordinate that will satisfy .equals(). For example:

```
Coordinate a = new Coordinate(2, 2);
Coordinate b = new Coordinate(2, 2);

A.add(a);
B.add(b);
```

Even though a.equals(b) and b.equals(a) both evaluate to true, a and b are different instances (and thus are allocated to different memory locations), and therefore every mathod of comparing the sets A and B that I've come across will evaluate them as different sets.

Is there a way to evaluate whether sets are equal based on whether their contents satisfy .equals()?

Answer (score 1):

If your `Set`s are `HashSet`s, you forgot to override `hashCode()` in the `Coordinate` class. The contract of `hashCode()` requires that if `a.equals(b)` is true, `a.hashCode() == b.hashCode()` must also be true.

Overriding `hashCode()` properly would result in `A.equals(B)` returning true, since `equals` for `Set`s returns true if:

> the two sets have the same size, and every member of the specified set is contained in this set (or equivalently, every member of this set is contained in the specified set).

One possible implementation:

```
@Override
public int hashCode()
{
    return Objects.hash(x,y);
}
```

Comment: While it makes sense to have `hashCode()` implemented, I think `HashSet` kinda is beside the contract of `Set.equals()` - which doesn't require hash codes to match. For a test of inconsistency, try `Set<Coordinate> A = new TreeSet<>(); Set<Coordinate> B = new HashSet<>();`, and `A.equals(B)` returns `true` whereas `B.equals(A)` returns `false`.

Comment: @ernest_k the basic contract of `hashCode` defined in `Object` class requires that it matches the implementation of `equals`. If you follow that contract, `HashSet`s will behave properly.

Comment: Agree with that, no doubt. But I just think `HashSet` is being odd among `Set` implementations here. --I'm admittedly nitpicking...

Answer (score 0):

Generate the hashCode and equals methods

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + x;
    result = prime * result + y;
    return result;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
    Coordinate other = (Coordinate) obj;
    if (x != other.x)
        return false;
    if (y != other.y)
        return false;
    return true;
}
```